# Python/Numpy - Get Index into Main Array from Subset

Tags: python, indexing, numpy

Say I have a 100 element numpy array.  I perform some calculation on a subset of this array - maybe 20 elements where some condition is met.  Then I pick an index in this subset, how can I (efficiently) recover the index in the first array?  I don't want to perform the calculation on all values in a because it is expensive, so I only want to perform it where it is required (where that condition is met).

Here is some pseudocode to demonstrate what I mean (the 'condition' here is the list comprehension):

```
a = np.arange(100)                                 # size = 100
b = some_function(a[[i for i in range(0,100,5)]])  # size = 20
Index = np.argmax(b)

# Index gives the index of the maximum value in b,
# but what I really want is the index of the element
# in a
```

**EDIT:**

I wasn't being very clear, so I've provided a more full example.  I hope this makes it more clear about what my goal is.  I feel like there is some clever and efficient way to do this, without some loops or lookups.

CODE:

```
import numpy as np

def some_function(arr):
   return arr*2.0

a = np.arange(100)*2.                              # size = 100
b = some_function(a[[i for i in range(0,100,5)]])  # size = 20
Index = np.argmax(b)

print Index
# Index gives the index of the maximum value in b, but what I really want is
# the index of the element in a

# In this specific case, Index will be 19.  So b[19] is the largest value
# in b.  Now, what I REALLY want is the index in a.  In this case, that would
# 95 because some_function(a[95]) is what made the largest value in b.
print b[Index]
print some_function(a[95])

# It is important to note that I do NOT want to change a.  I will perform
# several calculations on SOME values of a, then return the indices of 'a' where
# all calculations meet some condition.
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but do you want to find out the 20 indices calculated in the second step? How does the final `Index` relate to it?

Comment: @ejel: To try to explain it, let just say that some_function ignores the input array and just returns an array of random intergers the same length as the input.  Then `Index` would contain the index into b that has the largest (random) number.  The index in b really corresponds to some index in a, and that index in a is what I I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question.  So, correct me if I am wrong.

Let's say you have something like

```
a = np.arange(100)
condition = (a % 5 == 0) & (a % 7 == 0)
b = a[condition]
index = np.argmax(b)
# The following should do what you want
a[condition][index]
```

Or if you don't want to work with masks:

```
a = np.arange(100)
b_indices = np.where(a % 5 == 0)
b = a[b_indices]
index = np.argmax(b)
# Get the value of 'a' corresponding to 'index'
a[b_indices][index]
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear.  In your code, `a[condition][index]` returns the value in a, but I want the INDEX in a, so that `a[INDEX] = a[condition][index]`.  Is there an easy way to get INDEX from condition and index?  I imagine there is, but it isn't obvious to me.

Comment: `np.arange(len(a))[condition][index]` perhaps?

Comment: @ScottB you could also do `b_indices[index]`

Comment: @AlokSinghal don't we need `np.where(a % 5 == 0)[0]` since `np.where` returns a tuple (length one in this case)?

Comment: @drevicko `np.where()` returns a tuple of same length as the array's dimension, so it's always possible to use it as an index: `a[np.where(a > 0)]` works for any n-dimensional array `a`.  For 1-d, taking the first element of the tuple returned by `np.where()` has the same effect. But not so for multi-dimensional arrays: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays

Answer (score 1):

Use a secondary array, a_index, which is just the indices of the elements of a, so `a_index[3,5] = (3,5)`.  Then you can get the original index as `a_index[condition == True][Index]`.

If you can guarantee that b is a view on a, you can use the [memory layout](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#memory-layout) information of the two arrays to find a translation between b's and a's indices.

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this work ?

```
mask = S == 1
ind_local = np.argmax(X[mask])

G = np.ravel_multi_index(np.where(mask), mask.shape)
ind_global = np.unravel_index(G[ind_local], mask.shape)

return ind_global
```

This returns the global index of the `argmax`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd store the index based on the condition before you made any changes to the array.  You use the index to make the changes.

If `a` is your array:

```
>>> a = np.random.random((10,5))
>>> a
array([[ 0.22481885,  0.80522855,  0.1081426 ,  0.42528799,  0.64471832],
       [ 0.28044374,  0.16202575,  0.4023426 ,  0.25480368,  0.87047212],
       [ 0.84764143,  0.30580141,  0.16324907,  0.20751965,  0.15903343],
       [ 0.55861168,  0.64368466,  0.67676172,  0.67871825,  0.01849056],
       [ 0.90980614,  0.95897292,  0.15649259,  0.39134528,  0.96317126],
       [ 0.20172827,  0.9815932 ,  0.85661944,  0.23273944,  0.86819205],
       [ 0.98363954,  0.00219531,  0.91348196,  0.38197302,  0.16002007],
       [ 0.48069675,  0.46057327,  0.67085243,  0.05212357,  0.44870942],
       [ 0.7031601 ,  0.50889065,  0.30199446,  0.8022497 ,  0.82347358],
       [ 0.57058441,  0.38748261,  0.76947605,  0.48145936,  0.26650583]])
```

And `b` is your subarray:

```
>>> b = a[2:4,2:7]
>>> b
array([[ 0.16324907,  0.20751965,  0.15903343],
       [ 0.67676172,  0.67871825,  0.01849056]])
```

It can be shown that `a` still owns the data in `b`:

```
>>> b.base
array([[ 0.22481885,  0.80522855,  0.1081426 ,  0.42528799,  0.64471832],
       [ 0.28044374,  0.16202575,  0.4023426 ,  0.25480368,  0.87047212],
       [ 0.84764143,  0.30580141,  0.16324907,  0.20751965,  0.15903343],
       [ 0.55861168,  0.64368466,  0.67676172,  0.67871825,  0.01849056],
       [ 0.90980614,  0.95897292,  0.15649259,  0.39134528,  0.96317126],
       [ 0.20172827,  0.9815932 ,  0.85661944,  0.23273944,  0.86819205],
       [ 0.98363954,  0.00219531,  0.91348196,  0.38197302,  0.16002007],
       [ 0.48069675,  0.46057327,  0.67085243,  0.05212357,  0.44870942],
       [ 0.7031601 ,  0.50889065,  0.30199446,  0.8022497 ,  0.82347358],
       [ 0.57058441,  0.38748261,  0.76947605,  0.48145936,  0.26650583]])
```

You can make changes to both `a` and `b` in two ways:

```
>>> b+=1
>>> b
array([[ 1.16324907,  1.20751965,  1.15903343],
       [ 1.67676172,  1.67871825,  1.01849056]])
>>> a
array([[ 0.22481885,  0.80522855,  0.1081426 ,  0.42528799,  0.64471832],
       [ 0.28044374,  0.16202575,  0.4023426 ,  0.25480368,  0.87047212],
       [ 0.84764143,  0.30580141,  1.16324907,  1.20751965,  1.15903343],
       [ 0.55861168,  0.64368466,  1.67676172,  1.67871825,  1.01849056],
       [ 0.90980614,  0.95897292,  0.15649259,  0.39134528,  0.96317126],
       [ 0.20172827,  0.9815932 ,  0.85661944,  0.23273944,  0.86819205],
       [ 0.98363954,  0.00219531,  0.91348196,  0.38197302,  0.16002007],
       [ 0.48069675,  0.46057327,  0.67085243,  0.05212357,  0.44870942],
       [ 0.7031601 ,  0.50889065,  0.30199446,  0.8022497 ,  0.82347358],
       [ 0.57058441,  0.38748261,  0.76947605,  0.48145936,  0.26650583]])
```

Or:

```
>>> a[2:4,2:7]+=1
>>> a
array([[ 0.22481885,  0.80522855,  0.1081426 ,  0.42528799,  0.64471832],
       [ 0.28044374,  0.16202575,  0.4023426 ,  0.25480368,  0.87047212],
       [ 0.84764143,  0.30580141,  1.16324907,  1.20751965,  1.15903343],
       [ 0.55861168,  0.64368466,  1.67676172,  1.67871825,  1.01849056],
       [ 0.90980614,  0.95897292,  0.15649259,  0.39134528,  0.96317126],
       [ 0.20172827,  0.9815932 ,  0.85661944,  0.23273944,  0.86819205],
       [ 0.98363954,  0.00219531,  0.91348196,  0.38197302,  0.16002007],
       [ 0.48069675,  0.46057327,  0.67085243,  0.05212357,  0.44870942],
       [ 0.7031601 ,  0.50889065,  0.30199446,  0.8022497 ,  0.82347358],
       [ 0.57058441,  0.38748261,  0.76947605,  0.48145936,  0.26650583]])
>>> b
array([[ 1.16324907,  1.20751965,  1.15903343],
       [ 1.67676172,  1.67871825,  1.01849056]])
```

Both are equivalent and neither is more expensive than the other.  Therefore as long as you retain the indices that created `b` from `a`, you can always view the changed data in the base array.  Often it is not even necessary to create a subarray when doing operations on slices.

**Edit**

This assumes `some_func` returns the indices in the subarray where some condition is true.

I think when a function returns indices and you only want to feed that function a subarray, you still need to store the indices of that subarray and use them to get the base array indices.  For example:

```
>>> def some_func(a):
...     return np.where(a>.8)
>>> a = np.random.random((10,4))
>>> a
array([[ 0.94495378,  0.55532342,  0.70112911,  0.4385163 ],
       [ 0.12006191,  0.93091941,  0.85617421,  0.50429453],
       [ 0.46246102,  0.89810859,  0.31841396,  0.56627419],
       [ 0.79524739,  0.20768512,  0.39718061,  0.51593312],
       [ 0.08526902,  0.56109783,  0.00560285,  0.18993636],
       [ 0.77943988,  0.96168229,  0.10491335,  0.39681643],
       [ 0.15817781,  0.17227806,  0.17493879,  0.93961027],
       [ 0.05003535,  0.61873245,  0.55165992,  0.85543841],
       [ 0.93542227,  0.68104872,  0.84750821,  0.34979704],
       [ 0.06888627,  0.97947905,  0.08523711,  0.06184216]])
>>> i_off, j_off = 3,2
>>> b = a[i_off:,j_off:]  #b
>>> i = some_func(b) #indicies in b
>>> i
(array([3, 4, 5]), array([1, 1, 0]))
>>> map(sum, zip(i,(i_off, j_off))) # indicies in a
[array([6, 7, 8]), array([3, 3, 2])]
```

**Edit 2**

This assumes `some_func` returns a modified copy of the subarray `b`.

Your example would look something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def some_function(arr):
   return arr*2.0

a = np.arange(100)*2.                              # size = 100
idx = np.array(range(0,100,5))
b = some_function(a[idx])  # size = 20
b_idx = np.argmax(b)
a_idx = idx[b_idx]  # indices in a translated from indices in b

print b_idx, a_idx
print b[b_idx], a[a_idx]

assert b[b_idx] == 2* a[a_idx]  #true!
```

Comment: Yes I do understand how I can use the indices like that.  But for my particular application, that isn't what I need.  Probably my example wasn't the best.  This code goes into a function and the function needs to return the indices into the array where certain conditions are met.  So the function might be something like `def some_function(arr)` and it returns the indices in arr that meet a series of conditions.  I do not intent to ever change the values of the array.

Comment: See my edit.  I don't see any way to get the indices that locate a subarray in its base array.  That would be nice.  I think you just need to store the (base array) indices that you used to create the subarray and then apply them as an offset to the returned (subarray) indices.

Comment: If idx is instead a boolean array (by doing something like idx = a%5==0), then this doesn't work, though with a slight modification it could.  It then ends up being very similar to what Alok said.  As always, thanks for the suggestions Paul.