# Change certain values in 2D numpy array based on values in 1D array without for-loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

My question seems so basic to me that I am a little embarrassed to not have solved it myself. Despite consulting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508352/indexing-numpy-array-with-another-numpy-array#5508404), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802033/efficiently-index-2d-numpy-array-using-two-1d-arrays#44802535) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29040449/how-to-efficiently-index-into-a-1d-numpy-array-via-slice-ranges?noredirect=1&lq=1), I couldn't figure out, how to change certain values in a 2D numpy array based on values in a 1D numpy array without using a for-loop.

An example case with the desired result would be:

```
import numpy as np

# sample data:
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
b = np.array([2, 0, 2])
c = np.array([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]])

# for-loop solution:
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i][b[i]] = 0.9 * c[i][b[i]]

# desired result:
print(a)
# [[ 1  2 27]
#  [36  5  6]
#  [ 7  8 81]]
```

**EDIT 1**

After implementing a modification of Rafael's answer, I now get the desired result without a for-loop. To my surprise, however, the indexing solution is *slower* than the for-loop.

```
import numpy as np
import time

# set seed for reproducibility:
np.random.seed(1)

x = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10))
y = np.random.randint(10, size=10)
z = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10))

# for-loop solution:
start1 = time.clock()
for i in range(len(x)):
     x[i][y[i]] = 2 * z[i][y[i]]
end1 = time.clock()
print("time loop: " + str(end1 - start1))
# time loop: 0.00045699999999726515
print("result for-loop:")
print(x)
# result for-loop:
# [[ 5  8  9  5  0  0  1  7  6  4]
#  [12  4  5  2  4  2  4  7  7  9]
#  [ 1  7  2  6  9  9  7  6  9  1]
#  [ 2  1  8  8  3  9  8  7  3  6]
#  [ 5  1  9  3  4  8  1 16  0  3]
#  [ 9 14  0  4  9  2  7  7  9  8]
#  [ 6  9  3  7  7  4  5  0  3  6]
#  [ 8  0  2  7  7  9  7  3  0 16]
#  [ 7  7  1  1  3  0  8  6 16  5]
#  [ 6  2  5  7 14  4  4  7  7  4]]

# set seed for reproducibility:
np.random.seed(1)

x = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10))
y = np.random.randint(10, size=10)
z = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10))

# indexing solution:
start2 = time.clock()
r = x.shape[0]
x[range(r), y] = z[range(r), y] * 2
end2 = time.clock()
print("time indexing: " + str(end2 - start2))
# time indexing: 0.0005479999999948859
print("result indexing:")
print(x)
# result indexing:
# [[ 5  8  9  5  0  0  1  7  6  4]
#  [12  4  5  2  4  2  4  7  7  9]
#  [ 1  7  2  6  9  9  7  6  9  1]
#  [ 2  1  8  8  3  9  8  7  3  6]
#  [ 5  1  9  3  4  8  1 16  0  3]
#  [ 9 14  0  4  9  2  7  7  9  8]
#  [ 6  9  3  7  7  4  5  0  3  6]
#  [ 8  0  2  7  7  9  7  3  0 16]
#  [ 7  7  1  1  3  0  8  6 16  5]
#  [ 6  2  5  7 14  4  4  7  7  4]]
```

What is causing this? And, how can I realize a speed-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
r = np.arange(a.shape[0]) # same as range(len(a)) here, but faster.
a[r, b] = c[r, b] * 0.9

array([[ 1,  2, 27],
       [36,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8, 81]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since my real application is a little more complicated, I will get back to you if I have succeeded in implementing your solution. It looks promising though!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Unfortunately, I get an `IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3` even when applying your code to the example.

Comment: What did work for the example, however, is `a[range(r), b] = c[range(r), b] * 0.9`

Comment: I couldn't see the `arange`, removed the downvote :).

Comment: `np.arange` did speed the code up, indeed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @apitsch Glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like are actually masked arrays are slow. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760668/python-numpy-masked-arrays-are-very-slow).

This is what a user said in another answer.

> Keep in mind that MaskedArrays are more of a convenience than a real
>   solution. If you need to perform intensive computations on arrays
>   arrays with missing/undefined values, you're in most cases better off
>   dealing with the mask and the data yourself. Until a better
>   implementation of missing/undefined values is baked in the NumPy code
>   (which should happen some time soon), you are stuck with MaskedArrays.
>   Yes, they are quite slow, because they're coded in pure Python, which
>   of course cannot be as efficient as relying on some C code

Hope it resolves your doubt.